# Does an app still receive data if iOS APNS is turned off?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If the user turned off (assuming the user accepted to receive Push Notification in the app, but went to Settings to turn it off) Push Notification in Settings for an app, does this app still receive data sent in the notification when opening the app. This app does not receive/retrieve/request data in any other way except Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: No, it doesn't.